# How to reduce the number of items in the TFS workspace

Tags: tfs

I get the following,

```
TF401190: The local workspace XXXXXX;XXXXXX has 353943 items in it, 
which exceeds the recommended limit of 100000 items. To improve 
performance, either reduce the number of items in the workspace, 
or convert the workspace to a server workspace.
```

but how to reduce the number of items in the workspace?

I've consulted the following articles but still a bit loss.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2013/05/28/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces/
- https://mattyrowan.com/2014/07/21/tfs-local-workspace-limit/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace?view=vsts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some options:

1. Change your workspace mappings to pull down fewer files.  (Either map fewer things into your workspace to start with or set up what is known as *cloaking* for the parts of the workspace that you are not using.) This may not be an option if the project simply contains a lot of files and they're all required.
2. Change your workspace type to a Server workspace
3. Ignore the warning -- it's a warning, not an error. It's only a problem if performance is unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks. removing one (*BIG*) mappings from workspace solved my problem.

Comment: How to change the mappings to pull less files? this sounds exactly like what I need, but I really don't know what to search for

Comment: @Gulzar The term you're looking for is "cloaking". You can cloak files or folders to exclude them from being downloaded and managed within your workspace.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only way I've found to reduce the number of "local workspace" items. If I just delete the items on my local machine, TFS never knows this, and the "local workspace" number never goes down.

> The answer is, if you do a "Get Specific Version..." on the files [in Source Control Explorer], and select Changeset 1, the files will be deleted locally and the server will know this.  The color of the file in the Source Control explorer will go from black to gray and will have the phrase "Not downloaded" in the latest column.

[Source](http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs_top_tip/tfs_top_tip_11.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input, just that how Get Changeset 1 can solve the problem overall is not clearly explained.

Comment: @xpt Get Changeset 1 tells TFVC to get a certain item from version 1, the first changset of all collections managed by TFVC. As such, it is likely a version where that item does not exist. Technically, it can be any changset 1000, 9999 etc. Any changeset where that item doesn't exist